# Sonarqube 5.2 SQLServer connection

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, sonarqube

Since Sonarqube 5.2 is released, the jTDS JDBC driver is no longer supported. We used this driver to connect to our SQLServer instance, but we'll have to switch to the Microsoft SQLServer driver. We're running Sonarqube on Ubuntu and use an Active Directory account to connect to the SQLServer database. Because we're running on Ubuntu we can't use integrated security, so the credentials have to be supplied in the JDBC configuration for Sonarqube. This would result in the following properties:

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://sqlserverhost.my.domain.com:1433;databaseName=sonar;selectMethod=cursor
sonar.jdbc.username=someuser
sonar.jdbc.password=somepassword
```

This results in SQLServer in a "Login Failed" with the message "Could not find a login matching the name provided."

The next thing I tried was to connect with a username containing the domain, resulting in these properties:

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://sqlserverhost.my.domain.com:1433;databaseName=sonar;selectMethod=cursor
sonar.jdbc.username=DOMAIN\\someuser
sonar.jdbc.password=somepassword
```

This however also results in a "Login Failed" in SQLServer, the message here is "Attempting to use an NT account name with SQL Server Authentication."

What am I missing?

UPDATE: 
The Sonarqube log can be found here: http://pastebin.com/AGB9bTQG
I can think of one thing which is different from the jTDS connection url: 
the jTDS connection url contained ";domain=my.domain.com", which the Microsoft SQLServer driver doesn't seem to support. Therefore I tried the DOMAIN\someuser setup which SQLServer refused.

Comment: In the previous version of SQ (while using jTDS), were you using the same username and password as the current ones? In other words, have you only updated the "sonar.jdbc.url" property or you changed something else?

Comment: Yes, we've been using the same credentials for some time and only changed the sonar.jdbc.url and the sonar.jdbc.driver ofcourse

Comment: You don't have to specify "sonar.jdbc.driver", what value did you set?

Comment: I've set sonar.jdbc.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the same user as previsouly? Can you put the server log on pastebin.com and edit your question to give the link so that we can take a closer look?

Comment: I've updated the initial post with the log and added something what came to mind

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam: Can you give me an update about your research concerning this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver is completely different from the jtds driver. In order to use it, you'll need to specify the authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos parameter (please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558122(v=sql.110).aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2015/01/09/jdbc-this-driver-is-not-configured-for-integrated-authentication.aspx)
The problem here is that your Linux machine is most likely not in the same domain, so you'll need to configure kerberos on your Linux machine too. Your best bet would really be mixed mode.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string format has changed. No more :1443 or selectMethod

sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://sqlserverhost.my.domain.com;databaseName=sonar

Comment: Doesn't work either. The problem isn't reaching the SQLServer instance by the way. SQLServer just says it doesn't recognize the login

Answer (score 0):

The connection string setting needs to be in the format:

sonar.jbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://{server}:{port #};databaseName={db name}

e.g.

sonar.jbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:36549;databaseName=Sonar

Check in SQL Server Configuration Manager that TCP/IP protocol is enabled and to find the port number for the SQL instance you want to connect to. Note that the database name in the connection string is case sensitive and must match what appears in SSMS.

[image: SQL Server TCP/IP Port Settings]

Re: Windows Auth to SQL Server - you need to either use a SQL Server Auth user, or comment out sonar.jdbc.username and sonar.jdbc.password so that the SonarQube makes the connection under the credentials of the user running the SonarQube service; I don't think it supports impersonation.

Comment: That's the problem actually. Sonarqube runs on a Linux host, not using an Active Directory user account, but SQLServer expects AD users to connect. Unfortunately the jdbc:sqlserver driver does not support domain configuration and therefore makes it impossible to connect to the SQLServer instance with an AD user account.

Comment: Are you able to change the SQL instance to Mixed Mode Authentication so that you can use SQL Auth instead of Win Auth (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188670.aspx)?

Comment: I think that should work, but we won't activate SQL Auth, because of security. So, this is an answer to the question, but not the one I'm looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Our solution was to have a SQL Server account created with permission to the database and use that instead of using the AD/Windows account.